# Arabic diacritics ignoring in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a case where I want I use elasticsearch as a text search engine for pretty ***long HTML Arabic text***.

The search works pretty fine except for words with diacritics, it doesn't seem to be able to recognize them.

For example:

This sentence: **' وَهَكَذَا في كُلّ عَقْدٍ'** (this is the one stored in the db)

is the exact same as this: **'وهكذا في كل عقد'** (this is what the user enters for search)

it's exactly the same with the exception of the added diacritics, which are handled as separate characters in computers (but are just rendered on top of other characters).

I want to know if there's a way to make the search ignore all diacritics.

The first method I am thinking about is if there's a way to tell elasticsearch to completely ignore diacritics when indexing (kindda like stopwords ?).

If not, is it suitable to have another field in the document (text_normalized) where I manually remove the diacritics before adding it to elasticsearch, would that be efficient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use arabic_normalization token filter, it will remove diacritics from text before indexing. You need to define a custom analyzer and your Analyzer should look something like this:

```
"analyzer": {
    "rebuilt_arabic": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "decimal_digit",
        "arabic_stop",
        "arabic_normalization",
        "arabic_keywords",
        "arabic_stemmer"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Analyzer API check:

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "standard",
  "filter" : ["arabic_normalization"],
  "text" : "وَهَكَذَا في كُلّ عَقْدٍ"
}
```

Result from Analyzer:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "وهكذا",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "في",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "كل",
      "start_offset" : 13,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "عقد",
      "start_offset" : 18,
      "end_offset" : 24,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see diacritics are removed. For more information you can check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#arabic-analyzer).